# Jquery - simple multiplication assignment mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/ohrgw29y/#&togetherjs=4USeqx1oCx

I'm trying to make a column "price together" each cell in which would display two other cells of a row multiplied. I got it to "add assign" but cannot "multiply assign.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var price_row_total=0
    $(this).find('.subjects').each(function() {
      var price_attributes=$(this).text();
      if(price_attributes.lenght!==0) { 
        price_row_total+=parseFloat(price_attributes);
      }
    });
    $(this).find('#price_row_total').html(price_row_total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Supply</th>
      <th scope="col">Used by</th>
      <th scope="col">Periodicity</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Units</th>
      <th scope="col">Price per unit</th>
      <th scope="col">Price together</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>water</td>
      <td> 
        <span>plant1</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4><b> monthly </b></h4>
      </td>
      <td class="subjects">
        10
      </td>
      <td> <h4> liters </h4> </td>
      <td class="subjects">
        2.99
      </td>
      <td id="price_row_total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hay</td>
      <td> 
        <span>animal1</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4><b> one time </b></h4>
      </td>
      <td class="subjects">
        15
      </td>
      <td> <h4> stacks </h4> </td>
      <td class="subjects">
        1.50
      </td>
      <td id="price_row_total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. I'm not even a beginner in JS , I have no idea what I'm doing, sorry. I'm sure it's simplest thing ever but I'm too short on time to learn JS synthax right now. Trying to finish this volunteered project for an animal sanctuary. Hope this explains why someone posts such simple things.

Comment: *"I got it to add assign but cannot multiply assign"* - Can you elaborate on what you mean?  Where are you multiplying values?  What are those values at runtime?  What is the result?

Comment: For one, you have multiple elements with the same id.  That's not valid HTML.

Comment: I just figured out, you don't use [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) at all. Consider removing this tag not to confuse those, who might suggest related solutions.

Comment: @David I'm trying to multiply (instead of add) values of cells of columns 2 and 3 and show that multiplied number in a col 6 (separately for every row). I don't know what do you mean by "values at runtime but here's the result I'm trying to get:
Row 1: col2  [2]  col3 [3] col6 [6]
Row 2: col2 [5] col3[4] col6 [20]

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thank you and sorry for confusion, they got removed ! The first solution I was trying to implement was from dataTables docs, not this one; Nevertheless I included the tag just because if someone's proposed solution is unique to datatables , they'll know it works.

Comment: @illevens: “Values at runtime” would be the actual numbers you’re try to multiply.  Not what you might think they are, but what they actually are.  A great tool for finding this information is your browser’s debugging tools.  With the script debugger you can pause execution on a specific line of code and observe the real values of your variables.  This can help you find and diagnose future problems.

Comment: @David they will be dynamically filled with django tags  {{ like this }} which In my models I set to be DecimalField(..., max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, ... ).  These numbers will be added by admins and constantly changing

Comment: @illevens: That’s all well and good, but that’s not debugging.  Debugging would be identifying the actual numbers you’re multiplying.  For example, if you’re doing “variable1 * variable2” and the result isn’t what you expect, debugging will find what those variables are.  The rules of arithmetic are fairly straightforward.  If the values are “10 * 0” then the result will be zero.  If you didn’t expect that result, chances are that the values aren’t what you thought they’d be.  So the multiplication isn’t the problem, your assumptions about the values is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By no means is this answer elegant or even best practice, but it addresses you're current issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
      // this was modified to get price and unit based off class name (changed from subjects)
      const unit = Number($(this).find('.units').text());
      const price = Number($(this).find('.price').text());
      // the toFixed(2) rounds to 2 decimal places as these are floating point numbers you will end up with something like 29.90000002
      const price_row_total = (unit * price).toFixed(2);
      $(this).find('.total').html(price_row_total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Supply</th>
      <th scope="col">Used by</th>
      <th scope="col">Periodicity</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Units</th>
      <th scope="col">Price per unit</th>
      <th scope="col">Price together</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>water</td>
      <td> 
        <span>plant1</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4><b> monthly </b></h4>
      </td>
      <td class="units">
        10
      </td>
      <td> <h4> liters </h4> </td>
      <td class="price">
        2.99
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hay</td>
      <td> 
        <span>animal1</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4><b> one time </b></h4>
      </td>
      <td class="units">
        15
      </td>
      <td> <h4> stacks </h4> </td>
      <td class="price">
        1.50
      </td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, it does. If you have time, It would be cool to hear the reasons of why it's not elegant.